# Avoid YAML header change when switching knitr output format

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

Using knitr in RStudio, I have an rmarkdown file:

```
---
title: "PDF knit error"
output: pdf_document
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
---

#Content
```

In RStudio, there is a nice little dropdown option where I can change the output format:

[image: screenshot of Knit output options button]

However, when I use this to change between output formats, the YAML header is changed in an undesirable way (it is also changed appropriately, as the `output` value changes). That is, the `date` field, which has an R snippet to dynamically assign the value to `date`, gets munged-up because the double quotes are changed to *single* quotes, and the single quotes are changed to a *pair* of single quotes.

For example, when I use this button to change the out put format to HTML, the markdown file is altered to:

```
---
title: "PDF knit error"
output: html_document
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), ''%d %B, %Y'')`'
---

#Content
```

The `date` changes compared:

```
"`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"   # before another output option selected
'`r format(Sys.time(), ''%d %B, %Y'')`' # after another output option selected
```

This change causes the Knit to fail:

```
processing file: yaml-header-test.Rmd
Quitting from lines 2-7 (yaml-header-test.Rmd) 
Error in base::parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:29: unexpected input
1: format(Sys.time(), ''%d %B, %Y'')
                            ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> parse_only -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Is there away to prevent the switching of formats via the dropdown menu from causing edits to the `date` field? And, pre-emptively, yes, I recognize I can accomplish the change in format by editing the `output` field directly, but my question is about consequences of the GUI button.

System details:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- pandoc 1.17.2
- R 3.3.1
- RStudio 0.99.489

Comment: Maybe you should consider filing an RStudio bug report / feature request.

Comment: It appears to me that you are being stubborn. It was coded with a preference for single quotes. You can edit your input as needed. `'\`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")\`'`

Comment: @CL: Yes, that's a good idea. I just wasn't sure where the source of the problem (RStudio? knitr?), but even if it isn't RStudio, they'll likely know better how to track it down.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I can confirm your fix works, but the editing of the `date` field content by RStudio is still an unexpected and undesired effect.

Comment: Glad it works. Try submitting an issue report

Comment: This is a recognized bug in RStudio. See [https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209422797-YAML-dynamic-header-getting-munged-by-rmarkdown-rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209422797-YAML-dynamic-header-getting-munged-by-rmarkdown-rstudio).